# jQuery reset refreshing browser as well as resetting form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to issue a form reset to clear the contents back to there initial state. What is happening however, is that the form clears but also the browser refreshes. I have also tried putting the code inside a document ready but still the same. Can someone explain to me why this is happening. Thanks

```
<button id="AUSR_reset" class="resetbutton icon-right ui-state-default2 ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span>Reset</button>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


            $("#AUSR_reset").click(function() {

               $("#AUSR_adduser").get(0).reset();

            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to rest the form elements use a reset button within the form. It will reset all the form elements without any js help.

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
```

Comment: shankar but does that set the form back to it's initial state or just clear the form? Thanks

Comment: great suggestion. I did a quick test and using type="reset" on the button tag works as well

Comment: shankar what I am trying to is put the form back to it's initial state when it was opened not just clear the form. thanks

Comment: In that case you have maintain the original data in some json object or as data attributes in each field.

Answer (score 1):

Add `type="button"` to the button. Otherwise it acts as a submit button.

```
<button type="button" id="AUSR_reset" class="resetbutton icon-right ui-state-default2 ui-corner-all">
```

Comment: You probably don't need get(0) in your javascript. However @ShankarSangoli's suggestion is also a very good one. In fact using type="reset" on your existing button tag will do the same thing and JS won't be needed at all.

Comment: What I am trying to do is put the form back to it's initial state, not just clear it. Thanks

Comment: The reset() function in Javascript should do the same thing as the type="reset" on the tag.  I believe both will reset them to their initial values.